# Material UI - Keep Menu open

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to keep Material UI menu open after click on menu item?

I have tried `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` with no luck

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Material UI IconMenu component has a 'open' property which you can manage manually set to true to keep the menu open. And then set it to false when you want to close it. If you do this clicking on a MenuItem component will not close the Menu.

See the IconMenu documentation: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-menu

Answer (score 0):

The new material UI v1 use a `onClose` props like : `onClose={this.handleClose}`

You should just delete this props and it should works.

Check the [menu's documentation](https://material-ui.com/demos/menus/) for more informations

PS : React doesn't actually attach event handlers to the nodes themselves. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36319301/5176025) for more