# stopPropagation not working in Bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, typescript

I have the following accordion in my tsx:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 className="mb-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    Title
                <button onClick={this.onButtonClick} type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Testing</button>
            </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" className="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div className="card-body">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to prevent the `Testing` button from collapsing the accordion. Upon reading a bit about this issue, I came across `stopPropagation()` method, which I tried implementing in an onClick function:

```
onButtonClick = (e: any) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

However this does not do the job. Any idea how to go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work, but have you tried passing the event explicitly on the HTML, like `onClick={this.onButtonClick(event)}`? If you provided a JSFiddle, we could try it out before suggesting it. :)

You can also try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36319301/590525), since apparently React events **are not** actual Native Events, but *Synthetic Events* instead ([reference here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation)).