# React preventDefault for key event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using React Bootstrap typehead. I have this code -

```
onKeyDown={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }}
```

For IOS it prevents entering a value in the TypHead. But for Android, the preventDefault is doing nothing.

Is there anybody who has the same problem?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316846/react-onclick-and-preventdefault-link-refresh-redirect - similar concept, but also you could have a listener elsewhere that is firing

Comment: just check with  e.stopPropagation() instead of e.preventDefault()

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS e.stopPropagation() not working :(

Comment: @AlessandraMaria try these two , e.stopPropagation();
  e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();

Comment: @AlessandraMaria let me know did it worked or not

Comment: @EricHasselbring I saw the link but I have tried all those and still it didn't work

Comment: @AlessandraMaria whats the version of react you are using ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS 16.4.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185077/discussion-between-dileep-thomas-and-alessandra-maria).

Comment: use the keyCode like 13 or what ever the corresponding key codes write a if conditon to the key code and do the e.preventDefault()

Comment: @AlessandraMaria let me know whether that worked for you

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I saw the link...where can i declare
const node = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.autocomplete);
Because it gives error - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_react___default.a.findDOMNode is not a function

Comment: Just check with the key code, which key code you want to prevent