# How to prevent an <a> tag from redirecting user, while keeping its href attribute?

Tags: html, reactjs, web-crawler, anchor

I am working on a project in which we are using `<button>` elements as sort of links, as in, we open the page the user wants, difference being that we don't redirect user to the page, just render it in a `div`.

As we were discussing SEO strategies on another day, somebody mentioned how that was bad for our ranking in search engines, and how we should try using default `<a>` elements for that.

The only way I was able to achieve what I want is by setting the `href="#"` - which ruins the purpose of making the links crawable - and then calling `event.preventDefault()` on my `<a>`'s onClick handler.

I guess the question can be asked both ways:

> How to prevent an `<a>` tag from redirecting user, while keeping its
> href attribute?

or

> How can I make my links crawable while preventing them from
> redirecting the user, if clicked?

I have already tried:

- event.stopPropagation()
- event.preventDefault()
- return false;

And from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316846/react-onclick-and-preventdefault-link-refresh-redirect):

- event.stopPropagation()
- event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()

Comment: `a` tag is used to navigate, but you’re not navigating. Using `button` is right, your SEO won’t be ruined.

Comment: I've been trying to follow this guide from Google https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/links-crawlable

Comment: Your button isn’t a link and shouldn’t be crawlable.

Comment: Personally, I hate the load a page in a div pattern, I feel it adds additional complexity where it is not needed. I hope you are managing history so your users can still navigate using the back and forward buttons. The pages you are loading in the div, are the complete pages with doctype , html, head and body tags, or partial pages? If complete paged are you just parsing out what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will keep your href intact and prevent the page from redirecting there when clicked:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setContent("New Content");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <a href="somepage.html" onClick={handleClick}>
        click here
      </a>
      <hr />
      {content ? <div>{content}</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-bush-mmpvo?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Router to render components, and it's contain a Link inside the library you can use it to keep the redirect inside your app without refreshing, so you can replace the  with any .

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas.

1. If it is just for web crawlers you can use an invisible  element using CSS. That way you could keep you original solution. Web crawlers often don't render CSS.
2. You could put  in an iframe. That way only the iframe will navigate.

Also if you have a robots.txt file web crawlers won't need to crawler though links.