# A link inside of Bootstrap tooltip is not receiving a click

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I have this basic set up of a bootstrap tooltip to show a reason why item cannot be deleted. It contains a link.

```
<a
  class="btn btn-danger"
  href="javascript:void(0)"
  title="
    This element cannot be deleted, because it has some pending dependencies.
    <a href='/dependencies' class='text-white text-underline'>See dependencies</a>
  "
  data-toggle="tooltip"
  data-html="true"
  disabled
>
  Delete
</a>
```

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ container: 'body' });
```

**Desktop Chrome emulator**

Works as expected on a delete button click it opend the tooltip and when a link clicked in a tooltip, it redirects where expected.

**iOS Safari**

On a real device (i.e. iPhone) tooltip is opened, but the click on a link inside the tooltip closes the tooltip and the element beneath the tooltip receives the click instead.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't use an `a` tag when you want an action from a clickable element, you should consider using a buton: `<button type"button" ...`, that would give you control to control the `event` from the click event

Comment: @Harrison Is there any documentation on such approach to links?

Comment: I’m sure there are lots of other reasons beyond semantics, readability and SEO, some of these are discussed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715162/when-should-i-use-a-button-button-or-a-link-a-in-html)