# Is a <button> acting as a link bad for WCAG?

Tags: html, button, web-standards, wcag2.0

I've always wondered if using a `<button>` tag purely to link a page bad for Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG)?

When is it an improper and proper use of the `<button>` tag?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEO: <button> vs <a> HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201420/seo-button-vs-a-html-tags)

Comment: @Xufox: I don't think SEO and accessibility are all that related. There might be an overlap, but not much more I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the most common result of clicking something on a website?
>   Moving to a new URL, like you would clicking a link (Anchor) element.The `<button>` element, by itself, can't
>   do that.Button is a Form Element...

For complete article about differences of Anchor and Button:

https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/

Answer (score 0):

WCAG 2.0 guideline [4.1.2 Name, Role, Value](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#ensure-compat) starts with:

> For all user interface components (including but not limited to: form elements, links and components generated by scripts), the name and role can be programmatically determined […]

The mentioned *role* is [defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#roledef) by this:

> text or number by which software can identify the function of a component within Web content

So you would have to convey (for software) that your `button` element has the role of a hyperlink instead of a button.

In HTML5, the [`button` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#the-button-element) can have the [WAI-ARIA `link` role](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#index-aria-link). So using this role would be one way (maybe even the only way) to conform to 4.1.2 in your case, assuming that the software of your visitors supports WAI-ARIA.